Python multithreading performance degrades over time when running external shell commands
I'm using Python to handle multithreading where I spawn 20 threads to perform analysis and calculations on an external CP via shell commands. This process involves creating files, processing results, and running in a loop. However, over time (approximately one week), the execution time for these processes significantly increases. For instance, what initially takes 10 seconds ends up taking 30 minutes.
I've monitored the memory usage of the PC running these processes, and it stays around 40%. I suspect the delay could be due to memory consumption or issues with multithreading.

Without some logging of information it migth be hard to address. Measure PC stats from time to time and log them. Also log performance of most suspect parts of your system. If the problem happens after one week it will be long journey.. It may be possible to create workaround by something like restarting whole python script every day. Or at least delete and recreate thread pool or something.

Without being able to see your code, this is impossible to answer.
